# Combining an imshow colormap with Python Pandas subplot line charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, time-series, colormap

I have a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/) that has pairs of columns -- each pair has a *measurement* column that I want to plot as a line chart and another column that I want to plot as an `imshow` colormap to illustrate a *severity* metric.

A simple example:

```
from random import *
import pandas as pd

randBinList = lambda n: [randint(0,1) for b in range(1,n+1)]
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
tslist = {}
for measurement_num in range(3):
    measurement_name = 'Measurement'+str(measurement_num)
    tslist[measurement_name] = pd.DataFrame({'Value': randn(len(rng)),'Severity': randn(len(rng))})

ts = pd.concat(tslist, axis=1)
ts.head()
```

Results in a simple DataFrame:

[image]

My attempt to create my intended plot is based on: [Shade the background of matplotlib based on array and colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421312/shade-the-background-of-matplotlib-based-on-array-and-colormap) and [Colormap entire subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926383/colormap-entire-subplot)

```
PointList = ts.columns.levels[0].tolist()
y = ts[PointList[0]]['Value'].values
x = np.arange(len(y))
t = ts[PointList[0]]['Severity'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(PointList), 1, figsize=(18,10))    
ax[0].plot(x, y, c='black')

ymin, ymax = ax[0].get_ybound()
xmin, xmax = ax[0].get_xbound()

im = ax[1].imshow(t.reshape(1, t.size), extent=[xmin,x.max(),ymin,ymax], alpha=.5, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn)
ax[0].set_title(PointList[0])


plotcounter = 1
for point in PointList[1:]:

    y = ts[point]['Value'].truncate(before=cutoffdate).values
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    t = ts[point]['Severity'].truncate(before=cutoffdate).values

    ax[plotcounter].plot(x, y, c='black', )

    ymin, ymax = ax[plotcounter].get_ybound()
    xmin, xmax = ax[plotcounter].get_xbound()

    im = ax[plotcounter].imshow(t.reshape(1, t.size), extent=[xmin,x.max(),ymin,ymax], alpha=.5, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn)
    ax[plotcounter].set_aspect(ax[0].get_aspect())
    ax[plotcounter].set_title(point)


    plotcounter += 1


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which results in:

[image]

I'm having trouble with `imshow` for the first subplot. I'm looking for a much more elegant solution that integrates better with Pandas and results in subplots. Also I'd like to use the `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` as the x-axis instead of having only numbers.

Comment: You should first plot your x and y values, this 'shapes' the axes. And then get the extent of the axes (with `ax.get_xbound()` and pass that as the extent of the array.